# POST request to Paypal ignoring parameters

Tags: asp.net, post, paypal

Good afternoon,

I'm attempting to send a POST request from my ASP.NET web app to the paypal API to process a payment. The code below is the standard generated button code from the developer site with a few more parameters added by me.

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="testseller@mydomain.co.uk" />
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="myvalue"/>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<%:Article%>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<%Price%>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
</form>
```

However when the paypal payment screen loads, it has reverted the cost to 0.01 US dollars and seemed to ignore my parameters. On inspection, the `<%:Price%>` variable is reading as I would expect. Is there anything glaring I'm doing wrong in the above HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Hosted Button which is saved on PayPal side, you cannot edit the button code. PayPal will ignore any additional variable added / update to the button code. If you want to pass dynamic variables to PayPal end, then you should use non hosted button.